# How to use different dataset for scikit and NLTK?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, scikit-learn, nltk

I am trying to implement inbuilt naive bayes classifier of Scikit and NLTK for raw data I have. The data I have is set tab-separated-rows each having some label, paragraph and some other attributes.
I am interested in classifying the paragraphs.
I need to convert this data into format suitable for inbuilt classifiers of Scikit/ NLTK.
I want to implement Gaussian,Bernoulli and Multinomial Naive Bayes for all paragraphs.

Question 1:
For scikit, the [example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/naive_bayes.html#gaussian-naive-bayes) given imports iris data. I checked the iris data, it has precalculated values from the data set. How can I convert my data into such format and directly call the gaussian function? Is there any standard way of doing so?

Question 2:
For NLTK,
What should be input for NaiveBayesClassifier.classify function? is it dict with boolean values? how can it be made multinomial or gaussian?

Comment: There is a tutorial for working with text data in scikit-learn: http://scikit-learn.org/dev/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html

Comment: I tried installing scikit but could not find tutorial. My python version is 2.7.. Is higher version required?

Comment: The tutorial is on the website. Depending on how you install scikit-learn, the user guide and tutorials might not be included. But they are on the website. I'm not sure what more you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

@ question 2:

nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.classify expects a so called 'featureset'. A featureset is a dictionary with feature names as keys and feature values as values, e.g. `{'word1':True, 'word2':True, 'word3':False}`. Nltks' naive bayes classifier cannot be used as multinomial approach. However, you can install scikit learn and use the nltk.classify.scikitlearn wrapper module to deploy scikit's multinomial classifier.